# error with php subselect - Is there anyway to do a LEFT JOIN here instead?

Tags: sql, postgresql, php

I get an error with this `SUBSELECT`?

```
$common_dimensions_query = "
SELECT *
FROM main_products_common_dimensions d
WHERE d.product_id = (SELECT id FROM main_products WHERE abbreviation = '".$product."'";
```

The error:

> Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 4: ... (SELECT id FROM main_products WHERE abbreviation = 'banner' ^ in

Is there anyway to do a `LEFT JOIN` here instead?

Comment: That looks to be a quoting issue. Use prepared statements and your life will instantly become more enjoyable and fulfilling.

Comment: @bernie Thanks. Do you have a good resource where I could learn how to use PDO for postgresql?

Comment: I do not. However, searching SO or the web should yield some reasonable results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version with JOIN instead of double SELECT:

```
"SELECT *
FROM main_products_common_dimensions d
JOIN main_products p ON d.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.abbreviation = '$product'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the syntax, you should be using `IN` rather than `=`. The proper syntax would be

```
$common_dimensions_query = "SELECT * FROM main_products_common_dimensions d WHERE d.product_id IN (SELECT id FROM main_products WHERE abbreviation = '".$product."');";
```

Yes, you could do a JOIN instead. See the other answers for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your parenthesis

```
$common_dimensions_query = "SELECT * FROM main_products_common_dimensions d ".
                           " WHERE abbreviation = '".$product."')";
```

Of course I highly recommend against this query in general.  You should not insert strings into queries, use prepared statements instead.